# Use of undefined constant - possibly due to session_start()?

Tags: php

I might be missing something incredibly obvious here but inside my index.php file I have declared a constant, my autoload function and a class that has yet to be included:

```
<?php

define("DOCUMENT_ROOT", dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/site/');

$c = new classThatHasNotYetBeenIncluded();

function __autoload($class_name)
{   
    include DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

This works fine, up until I add `session_start()` to the beginning of index.php:

```
<?php

session_start();

define("DOCUMENT_ROOT", dirname(realpath(__FILE__)).'/site/');

$c = new classThatHasNotYetBeenIncluded();

function __autoload($class_name)
{   
    include DOCUMENT_ROOT . 'classes/' . $class_name . '.php';
}
```

This gives:

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant DOCUMENT_ROOT - assumed 'DOCUMENT_ROOT' in ...
```

I've looked around at previous answers and they all seem to be due to missing `'` around the constant's name in `define()`, but it seems that `session_start()` is breaking the constants?

It might be that I have a misunderstanding of how `session_start()`, `define()` or `__autoload()` works, but I don't really know where to begin.

Comment: It doesn't matter you `define` after `session_start()`. Should work file.

Comment: How about initializing the class first before session_start()?

Comment: I've just moved `session_start()` between everything and it's still producing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I use **DIR** instead of file and escape the "\" like this:

```
define("DOCUMENT_ROOT", __DIR__ . "\\site\\");
```

Comment: Windows understands '/' as part of a directory separator just fine, though there is also the in-built constant 'DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR', which is a bit too long for everyday use. __DIR__ is very useful though.

Comment: I used this because I had to store most of the paths generated in a DB, so other systems can have access to them :)